# Записать переменную в файл

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, статистика, анализ-данных

У меня есть [набор данных](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H81ZhdI91VFkjbo-d5n5VDMI3qaWEOJy4lZVjvyrrwI/edit?usp=sharing), на основе которых я рассчитываю некоторые показатели:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.multivariate.manova import MANOVA
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.stats.multicomp import (pairwise_tukeyhsd,
MultiComparison)

df = pd.read_excel('Датафрейм.xlsx', sheet_name='Vse', index_col=0)

MultiComp = MultiComparison(df['Harakteristika1'],
                            df.index)
pokazatel = pd.DataFrame(MultiComp.tukeyhsd().summary())
```

Вывод выглядит примерно так (несколько первых строк после перевода в DataFrame):

```
         0       1         2       3        4        5       6
0   group1  group2  meandiff   p-adj    lower    upper  reject
1      Вся     Общ    0.3831  0.2172  -0.1032   0.8693   False
2      Вся    Потр    3.0183   0.001   1.5115   4.5251    True
3      Вся   Произ     0.391  0.4985  -0.2459    1.028   False
4      Вся    Проф   -0.2482    0.05  -0.4964      0.0   False
5      Вся    Расп    0.8067   0.001   0.2382   1.3752    True
6      Общ    Потр    2.6352   0.001   1.0682   4.2022    True
7      Общ   Произ     0.008     0.9  -0.7607   0.7766   False
```

Это всё дело я записываю в Excel файл. Но я хочу сделать цикл, который будет рассчитывать такую табличку по каждому столбцу (на самом деле у меня таких столбцв очень много, несколько десятков, соответственно и табличек очень много). Записывать их на отдельные листы Excel, а потом сводить вручную неудобно, но свести в одно место все равно надо.

Есть ли легкий и быстрый способ записи всех этих табличек на одном листе друг под другом или нужно создавать отдельный DataFrame и только после записывать в Excel?

Comment: вы уже придумали как вы будете различать строки в результирующем листе, которые относятся к различным столбцам исходного фрейма?

Comment: Да, хотелось сделать отдельную колонку для каждой таблички, в которой будет содержаться название столбца, по которому построена таблица

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def get_mcomp(col):
    mcomp = MultiComparison(col, col.index)
    return pd.DataFrame(mcomp.tukeyhsd().summary()).assign(column=col.name)
    
res = pd.concat([get_mcomp(df[col]) for col in df.columns], ignore_index=True)
```

---

результат:

```
In [48]: res
Out[48]:
         0       1         2       3        4       5       6           column
0   group1  group2  meandiff   p-adj    lower   upper  reject  Harakteristika1
1      Вся     Общ    0.3831  0.2172  -0.1032  0.8693   False  Harakteristika1
2      Вся    Потр    3.0183   0.001   1.5115  4.5251    True  Harakteristika1
3      Вся   Произ     0.391  0.4985  -0.2459   1.028   False  Harakteristika1
4      Вся    Проф   -0.2482    0.05  -0.4964     0.0   False  Harakteristika1
..     ...     ...       ...     ...      ...     ...     ...              ...
91    Потр    Проф    0.9254  0.4907  -0.5712  2.4221   False  Harakteristika6
92    Потр    Расп    0.5026     0.9  -1.0775  2.0828   False  Harakteristika6
93   Произ    Проф     0.836  0.0027   0.1968  1.4752    True  Harakteristika6
94   Произ    Расп    0.4132  0.6753  -0.4026   1.229   False  Harakteristika6
95    Проф    Расп   -0.4228  0.2844  -0.9951  0.1495   False  Harakteristika6

[96 rows x 8 columns]
```